# React Native - initialRouteName not changing

Tags: react-native, react-router

I am trying to change dynamically the initial rout of my app, with a parameter that comes form app.js, but it does not work. Event sending a explicit "true" it does not work. The console.log show the right value.

app.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { RootNavigatior } from "./src/routes";

import { isSignedIn } from './src/services/auth';

export default function App() {

  const [signed, setSigned] = useState(false);

  useEffect( () => {

      isSignedIn()
      .then(  res => { setSigned(res);} )
      .catch(err => alert("An error occurred"));
    }, []);

    console.log("signed: ",signed);

  return <RootNavigatior signed={signed} />
}
```

route.js

````
export const RootNavigatior = ( {signed = false}) => {

  console.log("Routes_SIGNED: ", signed);

  return( 

    <NavigationContainer>
      <RootStack.Navigator initialRouteName={ () => signed ? "App" : "Auth" } >
      <RootStack.Screen
        name="App"
        component={SignedInStackScreen}
        options={{ animationEnabled: false }}
      />
      <RootStack.Screen
        name="Auth"
        component={SignedOutStackScreen}
        options={{ animationEnabled: false }}
      />
    </RootStack.Navigator>
      {/* <RootStackScreen signed={false} /> */}
    </NavigationContainer>

  )
}
```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you be more clear? Does the log in the app.js shows the value you're expecting or not?

I think the problem is asynchronous code block. When it resolves, initialRouteName already is setted, so its probably not you wanted. You can use "await" keyword to wait it to be resolved I guess.

Comment: Just took out the arrow function, and it's working.. 

Now it's like this:

initialRouteName={ signed ? "App" : "Auth" }

Thank you